# Bayes factor using BayesFactor package in R

Tags: r, bayes-factors

I only recently started using the BayesFactor package in R.
I was trying to extract the Bayes factor from the S4 object to add the figure to a table and saw that `bf@bayesFactor$bf` doesn’t give me the same BF value than when calling the object `bf` (2.85 vs 17.26 in the example below). Does anyone know why that is? The proportional error estimate is the same though (in the below example it says 0% due to rounding but i tested it with different data).

Example: using the sleep data from the package [website](http://bayesfactorpcl.r-forge.r-project.org/#glm):

```
data(sleep)
diffScores <- sleep$extra[1:10] - sleep$extra[11:20]

bf <- ttestBF(x = diffScores)
bf
```

Bayes factor analysis

[1] Alt., r=0.707 : 17.25888 ±0%

Against denominator:

Null, mu = 0

Bayes factor type: BFoneSample, JZS

```
bf@bayesFactor$bf
```

2.848327

```
bf@bayesFactor$error
```

1.681548e-07

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the BayesFactor package, the bf values are stored as natural logs and exponentiated when they are called up. So when you extract them you have to exponentiate them and then they will match your regular output.

So with your example data you need to do: exp(2.848327) = 17.25888.

Comment: Thanks Alex! Your blog was very helpful as well. I just wanted to add that my colleague mentioned something about extractor functions for S4 objects today which led me to `extractBF(x, logbf = FALSE, onlybf = FALSE)`. So logbf = FALSE  will match the regular output and logbf = TRUE will be the same as `bf@bayesFactor$bf`

Comment: Aha, very nice.

Comment: @AlexanderEtz, could you please take a moment and answer my question [**HERE**](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/261965/posterior-using-bayesfactor-package-in-r)?